# How can i do jQuery like coding in C language?

Tags: jquery, c++, c, linux, fedora

How to do jQuery like calls in C language?

Say we have a packets (html for example):

```
<div id="mymute"> 
 <div>
 </div>
 <div>
   <img src="/agents/sleeping.png" />
 </div>
 <div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Javascript/Jquery it query that packets and find the image tag and update the src attribute. using simply like this:

```
$('#mymute').find('div').find('img').attr('src','/agents/wakeUP.png');
```

But in C how can i do something like this? (not how to parse a string but how to implement such function().function().function().function().endless...().endless()?

main.c:

```
int
main () {
"This is a html string".cWayFind("is").cWayFind("etc etc").cWayModify(properties, tonewProperties);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think what you are looking for is being able to chain string extensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a great place to start:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining

Answer (score 6):

You probably want to use C++. There, it's very easy to return an object from a function which can reference the same underlying data. I.e. if you have something like

```
 struct DOMNode {
      DOMNode Find (const char* name);
 };
```

you can immediately type `DOMNode ().Find("foo").Find("bar");`, no special magic required.

If you want to modify the object itself, just return a reference to `this`.

```
 struct DOMNode {
      DOMNode& SetAttribute (const char* name, const char* value) { /* ... */; return *this; }
 };
```

Answer (score -1):

To do something like this usually you pass the receiver, i.e. `this`, as the first argument to each function call.

```
cWayModify(cWayFind(cWayFind("This is a html string", "is"), "etc etc"), properties, tonewProperties);
```

The most inner function call is evaluated first. The dot operator for method call is really just syntactic sugar to make the code more readable; The first action that is evaluated occurs first in a chained line of code.

Answer (score -1):

You need a jQuery type parser implemented in C++. At this point I do not know of any that exists.